# How to pass id for update query in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i am writing a plugin where i have to update the perticular row for that i have to pass id of that row, how to pass id for it ?

```
 <?php if (isset($message)): ?><div class="updated"><p><?php echo $message; ?></p></div><?php endif; ?>
            <?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>       
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->moving_from; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->moving_to; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->type_of_moving; ?></td>                   
                    <td><?php echo $row->moving_date; ?></td>                   
                    <td><?php echo $row->size_of_move; ?></td>                   
                    <td><?php echo $row->user_name; ?></td>                   
                    <td><?php echo $row->user_phone; ?></td>                   
                    <td><?php echo $row->user_email; ?></td>                   
                    <td><?php echo $row->user_address_1; ?></td>                   
                    <td><?php echo $row->user_address_2; ?></td>                   
                    <td><?php echo $row->user_address_3; ?></td> 
<!--               <td>   <a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=billing_form_update'); ?>">EDIT</a></td>-->
               <td>   <a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=billing_form_update'); ?>">EDIT</a></td>
<!--                    <td>   <a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=sinetiks_schools_create'); ?>">DELETE</a> </td>-->
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
```

in the below  php code i need that id , but i am unable to update it, when evr i am updating its just simply reloading

```html
<?php
function billing_form_update() {
  global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'billing_form';   
    
     $id =  $_GET['id'];            
    $moving_from2 = $_POST['moving_from2'];
    $moving_to2 = $_POST['moving_to2'];
    $type_of_moving2 = $_POST['type_of_moving2'];      
    $moving_date2 = $_POST['moving_date2'];
    $size_of_moving2 = $_POST['size_of_moving2'];       
    $user_name2  = $_POST['user_name2'];
    $user_phone2 = $_POST['user_phone2'];
    $user_email2  = $_POST['user_email2'];
    $contact_address2  = $_POST['contact_address2'];      
    $moving_from_addres2s  = $_POST['moving_from_address2'];
    $moving_to_address2  = $_POST['moving_to_address2'];  
    
     if (isset($_POST['update'])) {             
     
         $wpdb->update(
                $table_name, //table
                array('moving_from' => $moving_from2,'moving_to' => $moving_to2,'type_of_moving' => $type_of_moving2,'moving_date' => $moving_date2,'size_of_move' => $size_of_moving2,'user_name' => $user_name2,'user_phone' => $user_phone2,'user_email' => $user_email2,'user_address_1' => $contact_address2,'user_address_2' => $moving_from_addres2s,'user_address_3' => $moving_to_address2), //data
                array('id' =>  $id) //where
                
        );

    }
     


?>
```

Comment: `<td>   <a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=billing_form_update&id='.$row->id); ?>">EDIT</a></td>` try this

Comment: I would never put a delete link on my page. One visit from Google Spider and the dabase could be empty

Comment: @alive to Die , thank you , it worked,

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `id` in your link too, like below:-

```
<td> <a href="<?php echo admin_url('admin.php?page=billing_form_update&id='.$row->id)‌​; ?>">EDIT</a></td>
```

Now when you want to fetch it on `admin.php` use:-

```
$_GET['id']
```

Comment: can you tell me how to take the id from the url for updating it

Comment: using `$_GET['id']`

Comment: i mean for the above url where i have passed id

Comment: @ashishvc  i din't get you :- `i mean for the above url where i have passed id`

Comment: i have passed the id like this 'admin.php?page=billing_form_update&id='.$row->id , now after clicking edit i need id in other page where i am writing update query

Comment: on that page use `$_GET['id']` to get the `id`

Comment: what url is coming? id came there in url or not? `$row->id` giving value there in url or itself added as a plain text?

Comment: see when i edit perticular row i am passing id of it to admin page , so while updating i want use that id as a $id ,

Comment: @ashishvc  let me know What url is coming in browser when you click on the link?

Comment: Also why on that page `$_POST` variables are used? How you are getting those variables?

Comment: i have written a function inside plugin, where it will called to display form, and there only i have written post values